# Popup Box Moves Down after First Display on the Right

Tags: css

In this fiddle, the popup should display to the right of the '?' link when clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/eur6ao3z/13/

And it does, on the **first** click. But then when I try a few more times, it always drops down to the next line. Why is that?

Note the 'relative' positioning of the Anchor tag, and 'absolute' for the popup span -- this should keep it always to the right, shouldn't it?

```
.helpicon {
  position: relative;
}

.helpbox {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:394px;
  z-index:50;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note the 'relative' positioning of the Anchor tag, and 'absolute' for
>   the popup span -- this should keep it always to the right, shouldn't
>   it?

This is not true as you don't have an attribute to bind the pop-up horizontally except the `right:0px;` which I have added.

```
.helpbox {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  right:0px; // added this 
  margin-top: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:394px;
  z-index:50;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

Comment: with this change, the box is always skewed to the right corner of the page, rather than directly next to the icon's right: https://jsfiddle.net/eur6ao3z/14/